# Series behavior for self-defined function

Tags: functions, series-expansion

How to make Series give the correct expansion of a self-defined function?

For example, for some reason, I use `f[x]` to represent `1/x`. Its derivative behavior can be defined using `Derivative[n_][f][x_] := (-1)^n*n!*f[x]^(1 + n)`. Now `D` gives the correct derivative.

However `Series` does not work, `Series[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]` returns `f[0] - x f[0]^2 + O[x]^2`. This is a general result, but for functions with poles, this is obviously not what I want. So, how can I rigorously define these properties of `f`? Or to ask more broadly, what needs to be defined for `f` in order to obtain the expansion for a self-defined function in Mathematica?

In order to show my request, consider these code

```
Derivative[n_][f][x_] := (-1)^n*n!*f[x]^(1 + n);

(*Check the second derivative of f[Sin[x]], restore f to 1/x in the result*)
D[1/Sin[x], {x, 2}] - D[f[Sin[x]], {x, 2}] /. f[x_] :> 1/x // Simplify
```

returns `0`, which is what I'm expecting. However

```
Series[1/Sin[x], {x, 0, 2}]
Series[f[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

returns

```
1/x + x/6 +O[x]^3
f[0] - f[0]^2 x + f[0]^3 x^2 + O[x]^3
```

respectively. Is there any way to make `Series` give correct result for expression contains ```f```?

Comment: You can not define a Taylor series at a singular point. However, if you define a MacLaurin Series, it contains only ther term 1/x.

Comment: Did you define `f`? If I just run the series as is I get a different result from what's shown. `In[7]:= Series[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
Out[7]= f[0] + f'[0] x + O[x]^2`

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, I defined ```Derivative[n_][f]```, and it's the only definition related to ```f``` in my example.

Comment: @Daniel Huber, yes, since 0 is a pole, the expansion cannot be Taylor expansion. I'm not sure what the clear term is (Laurent expansion or double side expansion?) while ```Series``` does provide the  correct asymptotic behavior near poles, for example ```Series[1/Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 1}]``` returns ```1/x^2 + 1/3 + O[x]^2```

Comment: Try it this way. `In[1]:= Derivative[n_][f][x_] := (-1)^n*n!*f[x]^(1 + n)

In[2]:= Series[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, Analytic -> True]

Out[2]= SeriesData[x, 0, {f[0], -f[0]^2}, 0, 2, 1]`

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, I think this result comes from ```f[0] + f'[0] x + O[x]^2``` where ```f'[0]``` is ```-f[0]^2``` after define the ```Derivative[n_][f]```. ```Analytic -> True``` is the default setting for ```Series```, so maybe that‘s not the problem. Thanks for your response. Let me provide a more detail of the issue.